# What is the significance of the epilogue dialogue respective to the film?

Tags: analysis, dialogue, super-deluxe

In the film *Super Deluxe*, there is an epilogue long narrative quote about life which connects then to the porn film being played but what does it signify to the story? Is there any parallel to draw?

Comment: How does the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Deluxe_(film)) entry for the epilogue not answer your question?

Comment: @CGCampbell read the question again, I said how it's connected /relevant to the stories present in the film.